# restrict access to only one page in Zen Cart

Tags: php, mysql, zen-cart

I have a client who sell shirts that are available to the general public, but also wants to sell the same shirts for organizations through his site that aren't for the general public, such as company shirts, etc.

I figured out how to password protect an EZ page, so the general public cannot have access without a code to view; however, the password protect does not trickle down to the child EZ pages which I have located inside a 'Table of Contents'. My problem: I do not want the retailers to have access to view all the other organization price discounts. Currently, the password protect code is set up that once a retailer makes it pass the password protect EZ parent Page, they are able to access all the organization links. No good. Is there a way I can only restrict 1 page per retailer without them seeing the discount that their competitors receive?

I am not to sure if this can be solved using code or if this is a database question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is both a php and DB question. :)

What you could do is enable php under EZ-Pages and then make a per-page restriction based on customer ID. For example, you could do something like this:

```
if ($_SESSION['customer_id'] == 24 || ($_SESSION['customers_id'] == 48)) {
 //your content here
} else {
 //not authorized message
}
```

This will allow you to show the content only to customers ID 24 and 48. No need for password protection, it's all handled by Zen Cart's native code.

In case you're using Dual Pricing and your organizations have wholesale status, you could use `$_SESSION['customer_whole']`

It all depends on how you're handling your organizations...

Comment: Can you explain this a litte further? I am unsure what file to modify?

Comment: You'll need to enable php under EZ pages as described here: http://www.zen-cart.com/showthread.php?37252-PHP-inside-ezpages (there is a security risk, but I don't think there's anything else you can do). Then, you'll simply add the code I mentioned above to your EZ-Page

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I am still not understanding what I need to do to make this work. I have read through the forum that you linked me to and I had no success when I modified the files. Are there any other resources out there that would be able to explain this further for me?

Comment: Well, you should only read the first two pages, it's all quite well explained. This is a somewhat delicate process so be careful you don't skip anything. After you enable php to run on the EZ Page you selected, test it to make sure it works with some simple echo. If it works, then go for the session based code. I'm sorry, but I don't know of any other way or any other resources - this is how I usually do it for my clients...